# Решение функции по заданному условию

Tags: c#, функции, консоль

Здравствуйте! Необходима помощь с правильной записью условия в цикле в методе GetRes. Прикрепил скриншот функции и текущий код ниже.

[image: Решить функцию]

```
      static int Factorial(int i)
      {
          if (i <= 1)
             return 1;
          return i * Factorial(i - 1);
      }

      static void GetRes(double x)
     {
        double res, sum = 0;
        int n = 1;
        while (Math.Abs(x) < Math.E)   // здесь нужна помощь
        {            
            res = Math.Round(((Math.Pow(-1, n) * Math.Pow(x, n)) / Factorial(n)), 2);    // здесь нужна помощь
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            sum += res;
            n++;

            if (Console.KeyAvailable) break;           
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nСума: " + sum);
    }
```

Comment: [Math.E](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.e(v=vs.110).aspx) == 2.7182818284590452354

Comment: нигде не меняется `x`, следовательно цикл - бесконечен

Comment: Хорошо, а как вообще всё это правильно записать?

Comment: `Math.Pow(-1, n)` — мои глазааааа!

Comment: @VladD, ну формально верно же!

Comment: @Grundy: Формально, верно и `(int)Math.Round(Complex.Exp(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, n).Select(k => Complex.Log(k)).Aggregate((Complex)0, (p, q) => p + q)).Real)`. Но всё равно лучше понимать, для чего это там написано.

Comment: @Grundy угу, в этом и есть прикол ряда Фурье: n -> бесконечность => точность - регулируемая

Comment: @dgzargo, не понял к чему это относится

Comment: @Grundy ряд Фурье бесконечный, точность зависит от количества слагаемых

Comment: @dgzargo, и к какому из моих комментариев это было? :)

Comment: @Jack какой вариант использовал? очень интересно

Comment: Вариант с заданной точностью. Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариант с заранее известным количеством слагаемых:

```
    public static int Factorial(int i)
    {
        if (i <= 1)
            return 1;
        return i * Factorial(i - 1);
    }

    public static void GetRes(double x, int it)
    {
        double res, sum = 0;
        for(int n = 0; n < it; n++)
        {
            res = Math.Round(((Math.Pow(-1, n) * Math.Pow(x, n)) / Factorial(n)), 2);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            sum += res;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nСума: " + sum);
    }
```

вариант с заданной точностью:

```
    public static int Factorial(int i)
    {
        if (i <= 1)
            return 1;
        return i * Factorial(i - 1);
    }

    public static void GetRes(double x, double ac)
    {
        double res = ac, sum = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (Math.Abs(res) >=ac)
        {
            res = Math.Round(((Math.Pow(-1, n) * Math.Pow(x, n)) / Factorial(n)), 2);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            sum += res;
            n++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nСума: " + sum);
    }
```

но осторожно: последовательность должна сходится, я этого не проверяю

---

и/или сделать перечисление и упростить (немного) код:

```
private IEnumerable<double> Part(double x)
{
    yield return (double)1;
    for(int n = 1;; n++)
    {
        yield return Math.Round(((Math.Pow(-1, n) * Math.Pow(x, n)) / Factorial(n)), 2);
    }
}
```

сможешь еще и LINQ прикрутить:
способ 1^:

```
double sum = Part(x).Take(5)
.Where((res, i) => { Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {res}"); return true; })
                                        //вывод на консоль, я бы убрал
.Sum();
```

способ 2^:

```
double sum = Part(x)
.TakeWhile((res) => Math.Abs(res) >= ac)//пока точность не выше нужной
.Where((res, i) => { Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {res}"); return true; })//консоль
.Sum();
```